# C++ Qt4: Add slot with QObject implementation

Tags: c++, qt

I'm fairly new to Qt in general, and I would like to use some degree of reflection in writing a generic method for printing lists of objects.

I'm currently trying to hook up to the ui like so:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <QStringListModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ...

    connect(ui->print_books_btn, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(PrintList(BookList)));
    connect(ui->print_clients_btn, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(PrintList(ClientList)));
}

...
void MainWindow::PrintList(QList<QMetaObject*> list)
{
    list.first()->className();
}
```

My relevant header files look like so:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
...

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    ...
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QList<Book*> BookList;
    QList<Client*> ClientList;
private slots:
    ...
    void PrintList(QList<QMetaObject*> list);
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I believe I've set everything up with regards to the Q_OBJECT macro in the header files:

```
...
class Book : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Book();
...
}
```

Everything compiles without error, though when running I get this in the console:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::PrintList(BookList) in ..\LibraryManager\mainwindow.cpp:18
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'print_books_btn')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::PrintList(ClientList) in ..\LibraryManager\mainwindow.cpp:19
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'print_clients_btn')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Is it possible to work it this way?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I think its `QMetaObject` that I actually want to be using - so I can do `list.first()->className()` etc. Edited above ^

**UPDATE 2**

Required to be using Qt4.

Comment: Not with the old-style `SIGNAL()/SLOT()` macros, no -- but if you are using C++11 and Qt5.x, you can get something like the behavior you want using the new syntax and lambda expressions:  https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add I need to be using Qt4. I've updated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`released()` signals of QPushButtons would not send any parameters like QMetaObject* as you like to your slots `SLOT(PrintList(...))`

so your implementation is wrong,

you should think another way for example you take the `released()` [or `clicked()`] signals of QPushButtons and connect them to another slot in your class like `buttonsClicked()` then in the implementation of `buttonsClicked()` slot you should manually emit a signal with parameters like booklist or clientlist as you like to be received in the other slot `PrintList(QMetaObject*)`
this is how signals and slots are working in  Qt. Slots only receive parameters emitted by signal not any other parameters.

Comment: This put me on the right track - thanks!

Not really an issue with slots, turns out I needed an explicit way to convert my objects into QMetaObjects - that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should connect both signals to `SLOT(PrintList(QList<QObject*>)))`.
In the `PrintList(QList<QObject*> list)` you can use dynamic_cast to check what type it is (BookList or ClientList) then you can print what you want depend on its type.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5, you can use lambda functions in the `QObject::connect` method to pass a parameter to your slot:

```
connect(ui->print_books_btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [=] { PrintList(BookList); });
```

You can also use the `QSignalMapper` class to do the same thing in Qt4 (see the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html)).  Or, you can create two specific slots:

```
connect(ui->print_books_btn, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(printBookList));

void MainWindow::printBookList()
{
    printList(bookList);
}
```

The last solution is maybe the best way: it's explicit and more readable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add I need to be using Qt4.
I've updated above,

Comment: I've added an example for Qt 4 in my answer.